# IsEven Java project

Tags: java, arrays

Write a method  isEven that uses the remainder opertator (%) to determine whether an integer is even. the method should take an integer array argument, determine if the value of the element of the array is even,  then print the value. Use a for loop to iterate through The array.  Incorporate this method in an application that passes the array, inn NUMS[] { 8,16,9,52,3,15,27,6,14,25,2,10}

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now and im stuck this is what I have so far

```
public class IsEven 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        int[] nums = {8, 16, 9, 52, 3, 15, 27, 6, 14, 25, 2, 10 };

        System.out.printf( "%s%11s\n", "Number", "Even" ); // column heading

        for ( int counter = 0; counter < nums.length; counter++ )
        {
            if ( IsEven( nums ) )
            System.out.printf( "Even numbers are =  %d\n", nums );
        } 
    } 
    public boolean isEven( int even )
    {
        return even % 2 == 0;
    } 
}
```

can I get some help!

Comment: Is the method `isEven` supposed to check a *single* number or an *array* of numbers? Your question doesn't make that clear... For the latter: what's the expected output (when the array is empty, contains all even/uneven numbers, is mixed...)?

Comment: You are passing the entire array to your function `IsEven`, whereas the rest of the code is written to be looping through the array and checking each number individually.

Comment: it suppose to check all the array numbers.

Thanks for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it something like this.
Make sure you compare the differences
between this code and your code to
see where your mistakes were.

```
        public class IsEven {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

                // initializer list specifies the value for each element
                int[] nums = { 8, 16, 9, 52, 3, 15, 27, 6, 14, 25, 2, 10 };

                System.out.printf("%11s%11s\n", "Number", "Even"); // column heading

                // output each array element's value
                for (int counter = 0; counter < nums.length; counter++) {
                    if (isEven(nums[counter])) {
                        // System.out.printf("Even numbers are =  %d\n", nums[counter]);
                        System.out.printf("%11d%11s\n", nums[counter], "Yes"); // column heading
                    }else{
                        System.out.printf("%11d%11s\n", nums[counter], "No"); // column heading
                    }
                }
            } // end method main

            // return true if Array is Even
            public static boolean isEven(int even) {
                return even % 2 == 0;
            } // end method boolean
        } // end class IsEven
```

Answer (score 1):

change the line

```
if ( IsEven( nums ) )
```

to

```
if ( IsEven( nums[counter] ) )
```

Comment: thanks!! i didn't realize the mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

You have three *compile-time* problems :

1. You are calling non-static method `isEven` from static method `main`
2. You care calling `IsEven` instead of `isEven`
3. You are passing `array` of `int` instead of `int` to `isEven` method

And one *runtime* problem :

Formatting the output `"Even numbers are =  %d\n", nums` which should be `"Even numbers are =  %d\n", nums[counter]`

Answer (score 0):

here->    `if ( IsEven( nums ) )`

replace to

```
 if(isEven(nums[counter]))

            System.out.printf( "Even numbers are =  %d\n", nums );
```

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
if ( IsEven( nums ) )
```

to

```
if ( isEven( nums[counter] ) )
```

because the method accepts an int and not an array. Also calling methods is case-sensitive! (lower-case i at the beginning)

and make `public boolean isEven(int even)` static:

```
public static boolean isEven(int even) { 
    //...
```